# How can I preserve line breaks in html table cell when scraping with gocolly

Tags: go, web-scraping

I'm trying to preserve the formatting 
 in table cells when I extract the contents of a `<td>` cell.

What happens is if there are two lines of text (for e.g, an address) in the , the code may look like:
`<td>` address line1`<br>`1 address line2`</td>`

When colly extracts this, I get the following:
address line1address line2

with no spacing or line breaks since all the html has been stripped from the text.

How can I work around / fix this so I receive readable text from the `<td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know gocolly does not support such formatting, but you can basically do something like below, by using [htmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/htmlquery)(which gocolly uses it internally) package's [OutputHTML](https://github.com/antchfx/htmlquery/blob/master/query.go#L123) method

```
const htmlPage = `
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Your page title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
    AddressLine 1 
    <br>
    AddresLine 2
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
`

doc, _ := htmlquery.Parse(strings.NewReader(htmlPage))
xmlNode := htmlquery.FindOne(doc, "//p")
result := htmlquery.OutputHTML(xmlNode, false)
```

output of result variable is like below now:

```
 AddressLine 1
   <br/>
 AddresLine 2
```

You can now parse result by `<br/>` tag and achive what you want.

But I am also new in go, so maybe there may be better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`gocolly` uses `goquery` under the hood. You can call all [Selection](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection) methods, including the [Html()](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Html).

> #### func (*Selection) Html
>
> `func (s *Selection) Html() (ret string, e error)`
>
> Html gets the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements. It includes text and comment nodes.

This is how you can get the html content:

```
c.OnHTML("tr", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
    // You can find the elem
    h, _ := e.DOM.Find("td").Html()
    fmt.Printf("=> %s \n", h)


    // ...or you can loop thru all of them
    elem.DOM.Each(func(_ int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        h, _ := s.Html()
        fmt.Printf("=> %s \n", h)
    })
}
```